# Unable to launch Activity using an Intent-Filter in the Emulator Browser

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am new to Android and am experimenting with some of Android's features in preparation for project work.  Before I pose the question, I'll state that I have spent several hours googling this issue to only find the same answers, even on Stack Overflow.  I believe that I have followed the advice given on Stack Overflow and other sites (mostly the same answers), yet have not been able to get my problem resolved.

My problem is that I would like to be able to launch my activity from the emulator's Browser whenever the user clicks a link.  This is just for testing purposes; the next step is to do additional filtering on the intent-filter data.

I am able to get my activity to display in the activity selector dialog from my own WebView and from Messages.  However, it has never displayed in the Browser.  In order to make sure that it wasn't anything else in my code, I created a very simple app to demonstrate the problem.

My activity just loads up a simple layout with a TextView.  Below is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="14"/>

    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

        <activity 
            android:name="MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action 
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category 
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action 
                    android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category 
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category 
                    android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data 
                    android:scheme="http"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have also checked the Browser's Default actions, and they are empty.  Does anyone have any idea about why this is not working?

Comment: Your application MUST be set as default for this to work.

Comment: I'll raise the newbie flag.  How do I set my application to default?  I have the intent-filter category of DEFAULT, but I assume that there is more to it than that.  The only way I know to set an application to default is in the selector dialog, but since I can't get that to display, I'm not sure how to proceed.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated!  I still have not found a solution to this.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to get the intent filter to work in the browser you must navigate to a page and click on a link with the URL you are filtering. Typing it into the address bar will always go to the URL and never prompt to run the app.